# failed to deploy a stack: service "ABC" depends on undefined service XYZ: invalid compose project

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, containers

I tried searching this error and all the other people complaining about it seemed like they had simple issues (referencing container X when the container is actually named Xyz, etc), but I've been over this compose file so many times, I feel like I must either be missing something simple like that, or I've discovered/encountered a bug or something, which I suppose is also possible. Commenting out either the first or second service causes the other to complain, so they both have the same issue. Relevant Compose lines below:

```
version: "3"
services:
  gluetun:
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun:latest
    container_name: gluetun
    devices:
      - *omitted*
    ports:
      - *omitted*
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - *omitted*
    environment:
      - *omitted*
      # Timezone for accurate log times
      - TZ=America/New_York
    labels:
      - "diun.enable=true"

  first:
    image: *omitted*
    container_name: first
    network_mode: "service: gluetun"
    volumes:
      - *omitted*
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
    - TZ=America/New_York
    labels:
      - "diun.enable=true"

  second:
    image: *omitted*
    container_name: second
    network_mode: "service: gluetun"
    environment:
      - *omitted*
    volumes:
      - *omitted*
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "diun.enable=true"
```

Have tried many different formatting/syntax equivalencies, all seem to produce the same error. I should note I am using Portainer to deploy this as a stack, so that's probably the first half of my problem...

Comment: Delete the `network_mode` lines.